# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-asynctask

I am trying to get datafrom database in a list.

This is my code:

```
private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
    @Override
    
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    CharSequence contentTitle = getString(R.string.loading);
    this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(TabFreeBooksActivity.this,"",contentTitle);   
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {  
        this.progressDialog.dismiss();  
        showoffreebooks();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        // HTTP post
        sharedPreference3 = getSharedPreferences(downnplace, 0);
        downoptionplace = sharedPreference3.getString("downloadflagplace","internal");
        Cursor bokgids = ggp.gids();
        do{
            
            allgids.add(bokgids.getString(0));
            
        }
        while(bokgids.moveToNext());
        for(int o=0;o<allgids.size();o++)
        {
        
        ggp.unupdatduplicate(allgids.get(o));   
        System.out.println("allgids2: "+allgids.get(o));
        System.out.println("ggg: "+ggp.unupdatduplicate(allgids.get(o)));
        }
        
        getoffrecentbooks();        
    

        return null;

    }

}
```

the call of AsyncTask is:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo);
    frboks= new DAOfreeboks(this);
    ggp= new DAOgroup(this);
    sharedPreference3 = getSharedPreferences(downnplace, 0);
    downoptionplace = sharedPreference3.getString("downloadflagplace","internal");
    Cursor bokgids = ggp.gids();
    do{
        allgids.add(bokgids.getString(0));
    }
    while(bokgids.moveToNext());
    
    for(int o=0;o<allgids.size();o++)
    {       
        ggp.unupdatduplicate(allgids.get(o));   
    }
    if(isNetworkConnected(this))
    {
        connection=true;
    }else 
    {
        connection=false;
    }

    new LoadData().execute();

}
```

this is the implementation of showoffreebooks() function:

```
public void showoffreebooks()
{
     undelFREEBNME.clear();
     undelFREEAUTHNME.clear();
     undelFREEBCOVNME.clear();
     undelFREEbokprice.clear();
     undelFREEbokabout.clear();
     undelFREEbokpth.clear();
     undelFREEbokid.clear();
     undelFREEbokdel.clear();
     undelFREEbokgrp.clear();
     
     
     for(int  i=0;i<allFREEbokdel.size();i++)
    {
        ////////////////check my books if it's marked as deleted//////////////
        if(allFREEbokdel.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
        {
            undelFREEBNME.add(allFREEBNME.get(i));
            undelFREEbokid.add(allFREEbokid.get(i));
            undelFREEAUTHNME.add(allFREEAUTHNME.get(i));
            undelFREEBCOVNME.add(allFREEBCOVNME.get(i));
            undelFREEbokpth .add(allFREEbokpth.get(i));
            undelFREEbokgrp.add(allFREEbokgrp.get(i));

        }
    }
 
     System.out.println("undelFREEBNME.size: "+undelFREEBNME.size());
     System.out.println("undelFREEBNME.size2: "+undelFREEBNME);
     
 for(int i=0;i<undelFREEBNME.size();i++)
    {
        /////////////check if it's in a group of books or not////////////
        if(undelFREEbokgrp.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        { 

            GETFREEBNME.add(undelFREEBNME.get(i));
            GETFREEbokid.add(undelFREEbokid.get(i));
            GETFREEBCOVNME.add(undelFREEBCOVNME.get(i));
            GETFREEbokgrp.add(undelFREEbokgrp.get(i));
            GETFREEbokpth .add(undelFREEbokpth.get(i));
            GETFREEAUTHNME.add(undelFREEAUTHNME.get(i));
            
        }
        else
        {
            offlinegetgroupboks(undelFREEbokgrp.get(i));
            
            if(offfrgdbct.get(i).equals("false"))  // it tells me the Exception is here 
            {
                GETFREEBCOVNME.add(offfrgcov.get(0));
                GETFREEbokid.add(offfrgid.get(0));
                GETFREEBNME.add(offfrgnme.get(0));
                GETFREEbokgrp.add(undelFREEbokgrp.get(i));
                GETFREEbokpth .add(undelFREEbokpth.get(i));
                GETFREEAUTHNME.add(undelFREEAUTHNME.get(i));
                
                updatedublicate(undelFREEbokgrp.get(i));
            }
                                    
        }
    }
```

the implementation of offlinegetgroupboks(String id) function:

```
 public void offlinegetgroupboks(String id) {
        
        try{
            offfrgcov.clear();
            offfrgnme.clear();
            offfrgid.clear();
            offfrgdbct.clear();
            Cursor bookslist = ggp.fetchAlldata(id);
            
            if( bookslist != null ){

            do{
                offfrgcov.add(bookslist.getString(0));
                offfrgnme.add(bookslist.getString(1));
                offfrgid.add(bookslist.getString(2));
                offfrgdbct.add(bookslist.getString(3));
                
            }
            while(bookslist.moveToNext());
            }
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }

    }
```

but it gives me the following Exception:

```
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 1
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at cx.hell.android.pdfview.TabFreeBooksActivity.showoffreebooks(TabFreeBooksActivity.java:382)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at cx.hell.android.pdfview.TabFreeBooksActivity$LoadData.onPostExecute(TabFreeBooksActivity.java:191)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at cx.hell.android.pdfview.TabFreeBooksActivity$LoadData.onPostExecute(TabFreeBooksActivity.java:1)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the AsyncTask calling code. Also, returning null from doInBackground in this case looks like a bad design decision.

Comment: I edited it and added the call of AsyncTask

Comment: Also, please point to the line that actually throws the exception.

Comment: it tells me the Exception is in this line: if(offfrgdbct.get(i).equals("false"))

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell exactly where you are failing because the line numbers aren't present: you should show the precise line 382. However, you have this chunk of code in `showoffreebooks`:

```
 undelFREEBNME.add(allFREEBNME.get(i));
            undelFREEbokid.add(allFREEbokid.get(i));
            undelFREEAUTHNME.add(allFREEAUTHNME.get(i));
            undelFREEBCOVNME.add(allFREEBCOVNME.get(i));
            undelFREEbokpth .add(allFREEbokpth.get(i));
            undelFREEbokgrp.add(allFREEbokgrp.get(i));
```

You are assuming that `allFREEBNME`, `allFREEbokid`, `allFREEAUTHNME`, `allFREEBCOVNME`, `allFREEbokpth` and `allFREEbokgrp` are all exactly the same size as `allFREEbokdel`. Clearly, that isn't the case. Check the sizes of those variables BEFORE calling `get`.

Comment: I checked the size of them, they are all have the same size

Comment: There is a specific line crashing: `09-05 22:34:12.554: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at cx.hell.android.pdfview.TabFreeBooksActivity.showoffreebooks(TabFreeBooksActivity.java:382)`. What is that line?

Comment: the line is:  if(offfrgdbct.get(i).equals("false"))

Comment: Well, there you have it: your implementation of `offlinegetgroupboks` isn't filling the `ArrayList` with the same number of items in `allFREEbokdel`. Add a size check on that line, or check that `offlinegetgroupboks` is doing the right thing.

Comment: allFREEbokdel is with size 7 and in offlinegetgroupboks, the arrays are with size 1, so how can I solve this issue?

Comment: That sounds like there is a logic problem in your code, if you are expecting the arrays to be the same size and they aren't. You'll probably have to fix the logic and your exception should go away.